# Vlookup stringsearch

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I would like to perform a vlookup, but instead of searching for an exact match or partial match I would like it to search if the lookup value string is contained in the cell. Is there an excel function that will do this?

Comment: Please post some sample data with desired output

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

So, this doesn't work:

`=VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$5,2)`

[image]

#### 1. Use wildcards in the `lookup_value` to perform `CONTAINS`

First thing is surround the `lookup_value` with wildcards `*`:

`=VLOOKUP("*"&D2&"*",$A$2:$B$5,2)`

#### 2. Utilize the optional fourth argument in `VLOOKUP` to use approximate match

`=VLOOKUP("*"&D2&"*",$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE)`

#### Solution

[image]

#### NB

It will give you the first match containing the search text.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `VLOOKUP` here, you can use `SEARCH`:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("string",A1)),"Value if contains","Value if not contains")
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't do a lookup, however.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a list in column B and a lookup value in Column E, the following will work (if you have SPILL functionality):

```
=IF(ISERROR(
HLOOKUP($E$1,    MID($B1, SEQUENCE(1, LEN($B1)),  LEN($E$1)),    1,    FALSE)),
"","Present")
```

If you have the `LET()` function (I just got it last week), you might prefer something like this for a more structured appearance:

```
=LET(
SearchString,    MID($B1, SEQUENCE(1, LEN($B1)), LEN($E$1)),

IF(ISERROR(
HLOOKUP($E$1, SearchString, 1, FALSE)),
"","Present")
)
```

In either case, it uses `MID()` to create all the possible strings of length "whatever your lookup string's length is" which begin at each position in the searched string. This horizontal string is what `HLOOKUP()` then examines for matches. (If you prefer `VLOOKUP()` for some reason, wrap the `MID()` portion in `TRANSPOSE()`.)

If it finds a match, `ISERROR()` returns FALSE so it outputs "Present", and if it does not find a match, the output is "" (a blank cell). Of course, one could change those pretty easily. I prefer the "NOT-Blank vs.Blank" cell output when doing a visual search of a long list rather than "both results visible in the cells" begging me to screw up examination but that's just a recommendation.

One could also use the whole thing, or just the test, not the output, as input into a greater formula that returns, say, a list of cell addresses for the successful searches. Just depends upon how you wish to use the test's results.